# Changing app icon in order to change mini window icon

Tags: macos, applescript, dock, icon

I have an app bundle on my desktop. I change its icon by changing the icon in its `/Contents/Resources/` folder. This updates finder. However I am trying to update the dock.

I have figured I can changed my main dock icon with `setApplicationiconImage` (Objective-C) but I am having difficulty setting the image of the miniaturized icon on the mini window please see graphic below.

Apple docs say: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html)

> Cocoa applications can customize both the application's Dock Icon and a minimized window’s Dock icon.

So I know it's possible to set the minimized windows dock icon.

The docs continue on to say that it automatically sets the mini icon to be the icon of the App. Any way to change the App icon? So it updates the miniaturized app icon on the mini windows?

Thanks solutions in objective C are preferred, but core-foundation, applescript, and just regular file api via finder stuff is cool too.

Thanks

Here is a video screencast showing my dilemma: [Youtube :: Demo of Issue: Bundle File and Finder Icons Update BUT NOT Dock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8x5sCrj-kg)

and here is image of issue, (without me changing the icon of the dock with `setApplicationIconimage`)

[image]

Comment: do You want to change it while the app is running? What happens when You relaunch the app after icon change?

Comment: Thanks @MateuszSzlosek for your input so fast. If I right click on dock icon and click quit, then relaunch with app launcher, the icons take to dock and miniaturized, no need for `setApplicationIconImage`. However I'm trying to do it on run time.